# install.sh has python problems when installing Google Cloud SDK on OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to install Google Cloud SDK for OS X from here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-mac-os-x

I unzip it and then try to run the install.sh script by doing
    `sh install.sh`
but keep getting this error:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/bill/bin/bootstrapping/install.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I tried installing and uninstalling Python and also changing which version of Python the installer uses by doing
`CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=path/to/pyton2.7`, but it didn't resolve the iusse.

Comment: Same here. I tried running the command outside the folder so the "./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh" means its relative path and it worked. What did you end up with?

Answer (score 14):

For me, here how I solve it.

The google-cloud-sdk folder was in `/Users/MyUserName/Downloads` and I saw that I had the same command error:

> can't open file '/Users/MyUserName/Downloads/bin/bootstrapping/install.py'

I saw that the "google-cloud-sdk" folder was not mentioned in the path. So I said to myself that I should try to launch the full command in the upper folder and... it worked :)

In other words:

- I downloaded the file from: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/?hl=fr in my download folder (`/Users/MyUserName/Downloads`)
- I opened the terminal and typed: `cd /Users/MyUserName/Downloads`
- Then I typed `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`

Hope this will help! :)

Cheers,

Comment: That's it yeah you have to `cd ..` :face_palm:

Answer (score 0):

When I open Terminal the prompt is in my user $myuser. What I've done is to create a new folder in the Documents folder and move the unzipped google-cloud-sdk folder there. Then I call to the install.sh file from the Terminal.

1. Download and extract the tar.gz archive. We will get a folder called
   `google-cloud-sdk` in the downloads folder.
2. Move the unzipped `google-cloud-sdk` folder to any convenient location on your file system. For example, create a new folder called `code` in the `Documents` folder of your user and move it there.
3. In Terminal go to the new folder: cd documents/code
4. Write  ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
5. The SDK is installed.

Hope it can help anyone :-)